# how to build a graph from tuples in graphx and label the nodes after ?

Tags: scala, serialization, graph, apache-spark

Some context can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928133/how-to-create-a-graph-from-arrayany-any-using-graph-fromedgetuples/31929807?noredirect=1#comment51792711_31929807), the idea is that I have created a graph from tuples collected from a request on a Hive table. Those correspond to trade relations between countries.
Having built the graph this way, the vertices are not labelled. I want to study the distribution of degrees and get the most connected countries' names. I tried 2 options :

- *First* : I tried to map the index of the vertices with the string names of the vertices with the function idMapbis inside the function which is collecting and printing the ten top connected degrees.
- *Second* : I tried to add label to the vertices of the graph itself.

In both cases I get the following error : the task is not serializable

#### Global code :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val data = sqlContext.sql("select year, trade_flow, reporter_iso, partner_iso, sum(trade_value_us) from comtrade.annual_hs where length(commodity_code)='2' and not partner_iso='WLD' group by year, trade_flow, reporter_iso, partner_iso").collect()
val data_2010 = data.filter(line => line(0)==2010)
val couples = data_2010.map(line=>(line(2),line(3))) //pays->pays
```

couples look like this: Array[(Any, Any)] = Array((MWI,MOZ), (WSM,AUS), (MDA,CRI), (KNA,HTI), (PER,ERI), (SWE,CUB),...

```
val idMap = sc.broadcast(couples 
.flatMap{case (x: String, y: String) => Seq(x, y)}
.distinct 
.zipWithIndex  
.map{case (k, v) => (k, v.toLong)}  
.toMap) 

val edges: RDD[(VertexId, VertexId)] = sc.parallelize(couples
.map{case (x: String, y: String) => (idMap.value(x), idMap.value(y))})

val graph = Graph.fromEdgeTuples(edges, 1)
```

built this way, vertices look like (68,1) for example

```
val degrees: VertexRDD[Int] = graph.degrees.cache()

//Most connected vertices 
def topNamesAndDegrees(degrees: VertexRDD[Int], graph: Graph[Int, Int]): Array[(Int, Int)] = {
val namesAndDegrees = degrees.innerJoin(graph.vertices) {
 (id, degree, k) => (id.toInt, degree)}
val ord = Ordering.by[(Int, Int), Int](_._2)
namesAndDegrees.map(_._2).top(10)(ord)}
topNamesAndDegrees(degrees, graph).foreach(println)
```

We get : (79,1016),(64,912),(55,889)...

#### First option to retrieve the names :

```
val idMapbis = sc.parallelize(couples
.flatMap{case (x: String, y: String) => Seq(x, y)} 
.distinct 
.zipWithIndex  
.map{case (k, v) => (v,k)}  
.toMap)

def topNamesAndDegrees(degrees: VertexRDD[Int], graph: Graph[Int, Int]):  Array[(String, Int)] = {
val namesAndDegrees = degrees.innerJoin(graph.vertices) {
 (id, degree, name) => (idMapbis.value(id.toInt), degree)}
val ord = Ordering.by[(String, Int), Int](_._2)
namesAndDegrees.map(_._2).top(10)(ord)}
topNamesAndDegrees(degrees, graph).foreach(println)
```

The task is not serializable but the function idMapbis is working since there is no error with idMapbis.value(graph.vertices.take(1)(0)._1.toInt)

#### Option 2:

```
graph.vertices.map{case (k, v) => (k,idMapbis.value(k.toInt))}
```

The task is not serializable again (for context here is how topNamesAndDegrees is modified to obtain the names of the most connected vertices in this option)

```
def topNamesAndDegrees(degrees: VertexRDD[Int], graph: Graph[Int, Int]): Array[(String, Int)] = {
val namesAndDegrees = degrees.innerJoin(graph.vertices) {
 (id, degree, name) => (name, degree)}
val ord = Ordering.by[(String, Int), Int](_._2)
namesAndDegrees.map(_._2).top(10)(ord)}
topNamesAndDegrees(degrees, graph).foreach(println)
```

I am interested in understanding how to improve one of this option, maybe both if someone see how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem with your attempts is that `idMapbis` is an `RDD`. Since we already know your data fits into memory you can simply use a broadcast variable as before:

```
val idMapRev = sc.broadcast(idMap.value.map{case (k, v) => (v, k)}.toMap)
graph.mapVertices{case (id, _) => idMapRev.value(id)}
```

Alternatively you could use the correct labels from the beginning:

```
val countries: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = sc
  .parallelize(idMap.value.map(_.swap).toSeq)

val relationships: RDD[Edge[Int]] = sc.parallelize(couples
 .map{case (x: String, y: String) => Edge(idMap.value(x), idMap.value(y), 1)}
)

val graph = Graph(countries, relationships)
```

The second approach has one important advantage - if graph is large you relatively easily replace broadcast variables with joins.

Comment: Hum ok, I thought idMap could be seen as a function but I am not familiar with scala and we didn't use def so, I will try this, thank you for your reactivity, this is really helpful !

Comment: I added .value for the first solution you proposed, like that : graph.mapVertices{case (id, _) => idMapRev.value(id)}, but this is not working.

Comment: Fundamental problem is not how you use `idMapBis` (although for a `PairRDD` you should use `lookup` method), or even that it is not serializable, but a simple fact that it is a RDD. To access it you have to trigger action and you cannot do it inside transformation.

Comment: `sc.parallelize` is not the same as `sc.broadcast`.

Comment: your explanation was that idMapbis is an RDD, but idMapRev too no ? I mean they are the same type of object and I get the same error. Does the underscore in case(id,_) mean that only the first element is changed to idMapRev(id) or the couple is transformed is a singleton ?

Comment: second solution works perfectly but still I wish I could understand why the first doesn't work (thanks again though)

Comment: but thanks to you, I found how to make the first option work with `topNamesAndDegrees(degrees, graph).map{case (id,degree) => (idMapRev.value(id),degree)} `

Comment: `idMap` from my previous answer is `Broadcast[Map[String,Long]]` and `idMapRev` I created here is  `Broadcast[Map[Long,String]]` . If you want to use `RDD[String,Long]` and `RDD[String,Long]` respectively you'll need to go through a series of `join` operations.

Comment: I have the feeling that graph doesn't like mapVertices or vertices.map because I found a tutorial which uses this method and it provokes the same error (task not serializable) for me `val triCountGraph = graph.triangleCount()` `triCountGraph.vertices.map(x => x._2).stats()`. Maybe this is a problem of version or packages ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86725/discussion-between-zero323-and-stephanie-c).