# map nodeIds to edges GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have the following code which gives me nodes for `GraphX`

```
scala> val idNode = cleanwords.flatMap(x=>x).distinct.zipWithIndex.map{case (k, v) => (k, v.toLong)}
nodesId: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Long)] = MapPartitionsRDD[185] at map at <console>:32

scala> idNode.take(5)
res97: Array[(String, Long)] = Array((cyber crimes,0), (cyber security,1), (india,2), (review,3), (civil society,4))
```

I got edge List from this:

```
scala> val edgeList = cleanwords.map(_.combinations(2).toArray).flatMap(x=>x)
edgeList: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[187] at flatMap at <console>:32

scala> edgeList.take(3)
res98: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(cyber crimes, cyber security), Array(cyber crimes, review), Array(cyber crimes, india))
```

Now as `GraphX` takes `Long` Ids to create a graph. How should I map `idNode` with `edgeList` strings to create graph In `GraphX`

---

**What I tried:**

First I tried base on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928133/how-to-create-a-graph-from-arrayany-any-using-graph-fromedgetuples) as I am getting the below error:

```
scala> val t1 = idNode.collect.toMap
t1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Long] = Map(cyber  crimes-> 0, cyber security -> 1, india -> 2, review -> ...

scala> val edges: RDD[(VertexId, VertexId)] = edgeList.map{case Array(x: String, y: String) => (t1.values(x), t1.values(y))}
<console>:48: error: Iterable[Long] does not take parameters
       val edges: RDD[(VertexId, VertexId)] = edgeList.map{case Array(x: String, y: String) => (t1.values(x), t1.values(y))}
                                                                                                                  ^
<console>:48: error: Iterable[Long] does not take parameters
       val edges: RDD[(VertexId, VertexId)] = edgeList.map{case Array(x: String, y: String) => (t1.values(x), t1.values(y))}
```

As error is signifying, that there are **duplicate values** related to the `key` that's why I am getting Iterator but I have already ran `distinct` on this. So how to get rid of them now?
Also the above solution is not scalable for larger dataset as I am using `collect` in this?

Then another alternative:

```
val edges2: RDD[(VertexId, VertexId)] = edgeList.map{case Array(x: String, y: String) => (idNode.filter(_._1 == x).collect.toMap.values, idNode.filter(_._1 == y).collect.toMap.values)}
```

This is also not working.

Can please anyone suggest me how should I build these nodes and edges to build graph in `GraphX`. `Spark` version I am using is 2.1.0

---

**Update**

Able to find the solution for the non scalable solution:

```
scala> val edges: RDD[(VertexId, VertexId)] = edgeList.map{case Array(x: String, y: String) => (t1(x), t1(y))}
```

Instead of using **`t1.values(x)`** use **`t1(x)`** to solve the error.